# Custom SVG Fonts

Tags: css, svg, fonts, font-face

I'm using custom fonts in a SVG file to display a logo on a website. I'm having great difficulty, using multiple options to get the fonts to work, as they are not displaying on the live website. However, they do work locally.

The HTML tag I'm using to display the SVG logo is:

```
<svg width="263" height="26">
    <image xlink:href="/images/header-logo.svg" src="/images/fallback.png" width="263" height="26" />
</svg>
```

And for the SVG fonts I'm placing the following in the  section of the SVG file itself.

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Font-Name';
        font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
        src: url('fonts/My-Chosen-Font.woff') format('woff');
    }

    #text {
        font-family: 'Font-Name';
        font-weight: 700;
        fill: #424242;
        }
</style>
```

And for the  element:

```
<text font-size="34">
    <tspan x="29" y="34" id="text" style="font-family: 'Font-Name';">Company</tspan>
</text>
```

Comment: Your problem could be one of several things. You need to provide more information. Is the first SVG you list inlined in an HTML page, or is it a standalone external ".svg" file?  If the latter, is your web server serving the SVG files with the correct `Content-type` (`image/svg+xml`)?  If it's inlined, which browser are you using? Have you tried others? That could provide a clue. There is also a good chance you are striking browser privacy rules. See the section [Secure static mode](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#conform-secure-static-mode) of the SVG2 spec.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Pen that appears to work--let me know if this is helpful. It is based on the page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="290" height="40" viewBox="0 0 250 40"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <style>
<![CDATA[
text{
  font: 34px 'Ravi Prakash', cursive;
}
]]>
  </style>

  <text  x="29" y="34" id="text">Company</text>
  </text>
</svg>
<p>Read all about it.</p>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ravi+Prakash');
html {
  font-family: 'Ravi Prakash', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Hi WahhabB,

Thanks for your reply.

Unfortunately the fonts we're using are not available on Google fonts, hence using "src: url('fonts/My-Chosen-Font.woff') format('woff');", I'm starting to think that using fonts externally like this may not be supported by SVG format? Would that be a correct assumption, or perhaps it's best to use PNG or Google Fonts instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any external link like an image or font you have to declare your SVG with link capability.

```
 <svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 >
```

* SVG inside `<html>` tags doesn't need this specifications.